# How to render view in sitecore 7.2 MVC ..?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore7.2, sitecore-mvc

i'm creating a MVC application in Sitecore 7.2 MVC, i have install sitecore 7.2 & hosted it on IIS
i also added Views,Controller & Models folder.
i have created Views & now i'm rendering it using controller action in sitecore i'm a i'm a bit confused here i'm not able to find RouteConfig file so where i'll define HomeController & base Action which perform first..?

Any sitecore MVC expert please help me to how to perform HomeController Action for rendering a view.

thanks in advance

Comment: Check the documentation here: http://sitecore-community.github.io/docs/documentation/Sitecore%20MVC/index.html

Comment: first i thanks for your comment, actually i had seen it MH Walender's blog she explained there using sitecore 7.2 exe installer but i'm configure sitecore manually so i'm facing such type of issue.

Answer (score 4):

There is no manual registration needed. Once the view and the controller action method is created, simply create a new Controller rendering and fill in the Controller and Method fields with the appropriate controller and method names. Sitecore has a default route registered already and uses dependency injection to pull in the right control using the values from Controller and Method fields.

Answer (score 4):

As Vasiliy mentioned, you will need to create a Controller Rendering. Sitecore doesn't use the same routing engine as a standard ASP.NET MVC application.

Steps:

1. Create the Controller & Controller Action
2. Create the View
3. Create the Controller Rendering in Sitecore > Layout > Renderings (typically i organize my renderings in application specific folders such as SiteA, SiteB, etc...)
4. Add the Rendering to a content item

In the Controller Rendering item, you will need to populate the Controller & Controller Action properties.

[image]